# While installing ruby in windows i am getting this error ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension and yaml.h not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rubygems, frameworks

This is whole error:

```
C:\Users\prati>gem install rails
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/prati/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml
warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
error: clangarm64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: mingw32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: mingw64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: ucrt64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: clang32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: clang64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: msys: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: database 'clangarm64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'ucrt64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'clang32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'clang64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/prati/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.1.2/ext/psych
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-source-dir
        --without-libyaml-source-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-dir
        --without-yaml-0.1-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-include
        --without-yaml-0.1-include=${yaml-0.1-dir}/include
        --with-yaml-0.1-lib
        --without-yaml-0.1-lib=${yaml-0.1-dir}/lib
        --with-yaml-0.1-config
        --without-yaml-0.1-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --without-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include
        --without-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --with-libyaml-lib
        --without-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Users/prati/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/psych-5.1.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/prati/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.1.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/prati/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/psych-5.1.2/gem_make.out
```

I have tried

```
pacman-key --init
```

but it too gave this error:

'pacman-key' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have also searched on chatGPT about how to install yaml.h in windows 11, it said:

For Windows, you typically don't need to install additional development headers separately as you might do on Unix-like systems.

Comment: Wow ChatGTP didn't solve it, what a shame.

Comment: If I were you I would 1) use docker or 2) reinstall ruby

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sir.
Installed successfully when i hit the same command by opening command prompt as administrator

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time and grief by installing WSL2 and Ubuntu. You're probably not going to be deploying to a windows server anyways and you can actually follow tutorials and the commands in them instead of wasting time figuring out how to do it in windows.